# How to make the onremovefile on Filepond?

Tags: reactjs, filepond

I want to get the file of which I am deleting on `Filepond`. However when I use `onremovefile={(file) => this.handleRemove(file)}`, the `file` returns to `null`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution! The first parameter is a possible error response and the second one is the file item. Thus it's actually `onremovefile={(errRes, file) => this.handleRemove(errRes, file)}`